# Sample size for out of specification probability?

Tags: sample-size

I have a product batch that contains 100000 units. These units are supposed to have the same weight (their specification is Target value (in kg) +/- 10%). I would like to conduct a statistical test in order to inspect the conformity of this batch, in terms of weight (For example I want to make sure only 1% of this batch's products are out of the specifications). Since I cannot weigh all the 100000 units, **how many units should I take in order to have a proper estimation of the out-of-specification probability?**

**NB1**: Normally the weight of the products should follow a Normal distribution. However, since I suspect that there is a problem in my batch (which can impact the weight of some or all the units), I am not sure if can use the Normal distribution in this case. If not, what are the alternatives and solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in doing a hypothesis test comparing a sample proportion (the proportion of your batch that is out of specification) to some reference proportion (in your example, 0.01). In particular, it seems you want to do a one-sided hypothesis test, since presumably you are only concerned if the proportion out of specification exceeds some desired value. To figure out the sample size you need, you can use a sample size calculator like [this one](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/%7Erollin/stats/ssize/b1.html).

In the calculator linked above, the quantity $p_0$ is the proportion you wish to compare your estimated proportion to (from your example, 0.01). The quantity $p_1$ should be selected so that $|p_0-p_1|$ is the smallest difference you want to be able to detect. For instance, if you are interested in whether your estimated proportion out of specification is less than 0.01 or not, what level of error would you find acceptable? Would it be okay if the test result states that your estimated proportion is less than 0.01, but in reality it is 0.011? Or 0.0105? The smaller the level of error needs to be, the larger the sample size will be.

The other two quantities, $\alpha$ and power, also govern uncertainty in the statistical results. The former represents the probability that the test will state that your estimated proportion is greater than $p_0$ when in reality it is not (i.e. a mistake). The latter is the probability that the test will state your estimated proportion is greater than $p_0$ when it really is (i.e. what you would want). Setting the former smaller, or the latter larger, will both increase the sample size needed.

Finally, make sure you select one-sided instead of two-sided, and you should be good to go with this calculator!